# Are there times when combining business logic and data structures is a good idea?

Tags: c#, data-structures, business-logic

I've recently been told that if programming a data structure that--for the time being--will only need one type of business logic, I should build all the logic directly into the class and  only worry about moving it into a separate class when the structure needs different logic.

My question is: Is this good practice, or is it better to separate the logic and structure from the beginning if there is a reasonable potential that the business logic will change?

My gut instinct is to keep the logic separate, as that seems to follow the open/closed principle, and combining structure and logic seems to violate SRP.

Comment: On the other hand, are you likely to build data structures that contain *no* logic of their own? And, see also [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The only logic a data structure needs to (and should) contain is concerned with how to store and query generic data.

Comment: @delnan - okay, so that's a rejection of the entire Object Oriented approach. I'm not saying it's wrong, just that it's not yet necessarily mainstream.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever No, that's separation of concerns. Are you saying "the entire object oriented approach" consists of intermingling concerns such as organizing objects and the behavior of those objects? That'd be news. This principle is very much mainstream, basically every language's standard library containers follow it. Look at Java's collections, C++'s standard containers, C#'s `System.Collections`, etc.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, many, many data structures contain no logic of their own.  See for example every usage of an anonymous type.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty subjective question and essentially strikes at the heart of object-oriented programming, in which combining data and logic is the norm.  I generally prefer to keep the data structure separate from associated logic if the data structure is used for communication with another system (essentially following an Interface Definition Language approach), or if there are cases where the logic is specific to a very specific context.

In cases like lists, queues and dictionaries in object-oriented languages, the data and logic combine to form a cohesive object, and are mutually dependent.  In those cases, separating the logic and the data would not really make sense in an object-oriented language like C#.

However, in other, specific cases, it would make sense to separate the data and logic.  For example, if you're creating an Invoice object, and it needs to be processed by any number of downstream systems, then you don't want to put the logic for those downstream systems in your Invoice.  Instead, that logic should be separated out.

So, I guess the short answer is: It really depends on what you're doing.

Hope this helps,
Nate

Comment: Agreed about lists, etc. I think what I'm trying to ask is along the lines of... If I need to convert from type Foo to type List, I wouldn't extend List to consume Foo as new List(Foo) or List.Add(Foo). I'd make a method or interface that handled the translation and returned the List. Similarly for a database, I might have a class to allow adding, removing, creating, etc., but the logic for taking raw data and putting it into the database would be separate, using the database's Add() method. Is that right? And are there times when it's right to combine the two?

Comment: @Josh, again it depends.  In the database case, I generally agree with you and don't combine the data structure with the database code because it does represent a pretty strong separation of concerns.  However, there's a very popular pattern called ActiveRecord (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record and http://www.castleproject.org/projects/activerecord/ for details) that does combine something like your database .Add() method with the data structure.